# How can I access the history of Alt-F2 commands?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell

I use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> command line to launch a few applications in Ubuntu 17.10, e.g. `firefox www.facebook.com`, but the history of the commands doesn't appear when I start typing.

Is there a way to display the history as an options for commands entered in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> box?

Comment: No, while gnome-shell will store previous run command in gsettings they don't provide any user means to retrieve other than they can be viewed in dconf-editor. Maybe there is a gnome-shell extension for this, maybe not, try searching..

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> can open a file for you with the default application associated to the file-type if you put the path to the file. So simply typing `.bash_history` in the prompt and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> should open your Terminal commands history with the default text editor.

If you just want to run a command from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> prompt which you ran before using the same prompt, you can just use <kbd>↑</kbd> (up arrow) to navigate through older commands.